# ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE in Chrome

Tags: javascript, java, google-chrome

I am trying to run a website I created via netbeans, using chrome and firefox simultaneously. I have a multiplayer maze game, when I move, the server sends the other player that I moved. it works the first 3 moves and then returns `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`. I tried clearing history, incognito mode restart and many other solutions I found on the web.

This is my JS code:

```
   function opponentMove() {
     var url = "/AsyncMulti?sendToServer=" + sendToServer;
     $.ajax({
     url: url,
     method: 'GET',
     //dataType: 'json',
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     cache: false,
     success: function (data) {
        //parseData(data);
        sendToServer = "wait for play";
        moveOther((data.maze).toString());
        setTimeout(
                opponentMove, /* Request next opponent move */
                500 /* ..after .5 seconds */
            );
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
            setTimeout(
                opponentMove, /* Try again after.. */
                1000); /* milliseconds (1 second) */
        }
     });
  }
```

java code:

```
    @WebServlet(name = "AsyncMulti",
    asyncSupported = true,
    urlPatterns = {"/AsyncMulti"})
    public class AsyncMulti extends HttpServlet {
    Enumeration<String> e;
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)     throws IOException {
    SessionDB c = SessionDB.getInstance();
    System.out.println("LongPollingServlet.doGet()");
    String s = req.getSession().getId();
    MultiPlayer m = c.Socket(req.getSession().getId());
    e = req.getParameterNames();
    m.SetSendMessae(req.getParameter("sendToServer"));
    boolean asyncSupported = req.isAsyncSupported();
    System.out.println("asyncSupported 1: " + asyncSupported);
    // Tomcat only
    req.setAttribute("org.apache.catalina.ASYNC_SUPPORTED", true);
    asyncSupported = req.isAsyncSupported();
    System.out.println("asyncSupported 2: " + asyncSupported);
    if (asyncSupported) {
        AsyncContext asyncCtx = req.startAsync(req, res);// req.startAsync();
        asyncCtx.setTimeout(0); // => disable timeout
        AsyncRunnable thread = new AsyncRunnable(asyncCtx);
        asyncCtx.start(thread);
    }
}
}

  class AsyncRunnable implements Runnable {

private final AsyncContext asyncContext;

public AsyncRunnable(AsyncContext asyncContext) {
    this.asyncContext = asyncContext;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) asyncContext.getRequest();
    SessionDB c = SessionDB.getInstance();
    HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) asyncContext.getResponse();
    PrintWriter pw = null;
    MultiPlayer m = c.Socket(req.getSession().getId());
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    String s = m.getRecieveFromServer();
    int i;
    if (c.isMulty && !s.contains("right") && !s.contains("left") &&
            !s.contains("down") && !s.contains("up")) 
        sb.append('p');
    if( s.contains("right") || s.contains("left") ||
            s.contains("down") || s.contains("up"))
        sb.append(s);
    if (s.contains("pla"))
        c.setFlag();
    if (s.contains("Maze")){

        i = s.indexOf("Maze");
        for (i += 7; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (s.charAt(i) == '"') {
                break;
            }
            sb.append(s.charAt(i));
        }
        i = s.indexOf("Maze", i);
        //   sb.append('*');
        for (i += 7; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (s.charAt(i) == '"') {
                break;
            }
            sb.append(s.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    HttpServletResponse peer = (HttpServletResponse) asyncContext.getResponse();
    try {
        try {
            obj.put("maze", sb);
        } catch (JSONException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AsyncRunnable.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        peer.getWriter().write(obj.toString());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AsyncRunnable.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    res.setContentType("application/json");
    asyncContext.complete();
    System.out.println("After calling complete");
}
}
```